# Get the div position and add some pixel to some div - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the current **top** position of `.top` class div, then i have to add some 20px+.top into the `.bottom` inline style.

Ex: if `.top` has `top:200px;` the `.bottom` must be changed to `top:220px;`

```js
funtion(){
var position = $('.top').offset();
$('.bottom').css(position)+20px;
}
```

```css
.parent
{
  position: relative;
}
.child
{
  position: absolute;
}
.top
{
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  
}
.bottom
{
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child top">Top</div>
  <div class="child bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    funtion(){
    var position= $('.top').offset();
    var top= position.top;
    var left = position.left;
    var newtop = top + 20 + "px";
    var newleft = left + 20+ "px";

    $('.bottom').css( {
    'position': 'absolute', // if require
        'left': newleft,
        'top': newtop 
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This might do the work:

```
var topPosition = $('.top').offset().top;
$('.bottom').css('top',(topPosition+20)+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet for this,

```
$( '.bottom' ).css( 'top', $('.top').css('top'));
$( '.bottom' ).css( 'top', '+=20px' );
```